# how to get frame of Selected TableView Cell using UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm currently working on ChatScreen and I would like to add Archive Functionality.

There are two cell right now in my `TableView`.

I'm adding `LongPressGesture` to Open View.

```
CGRect myRect = [tblView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer  *lpgr  = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
           initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressReceiverText:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
lpgr.delegate = self;
myRect = [tblView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

This is the LongPress gesture implementation

```
- (void) handleLongPressReceiverText: (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  if  (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       CGPoint p = [lpgr locationInView:tblView];
       NSLog(@"%f",p.x);

       _ReceivertextView.frame = CGRectMake(p.x,p.y,_ReceivertextView.frame.size.width, 40);
       [self.view addSubview: self.ReceivertextView];
       [self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.ReceivertextView];
  }
  if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
  {
      NSLog(@"longTouch UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
  } 
}
```

I would like to get exact location of a particular Cell, which I tapped using `LongPressGesture`.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following code to get the frame of selected cell

Adding Guesture to TableView in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture  = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPressGesture.delegate = self;
longPressGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;

[self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
```

Handle Logpress Event

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        NSLog(@"Gesture Started ");

        UITableView *selectedTableView=(UITableView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:selectedTableView];

        //Getting Indexpath
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [selectedTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

        if (indexPath == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
        }
        else
        {
            // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
            UITableViewCell *cell =
            [selectedTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            //Here is your frame of cell
            NSLog(@"Cell Frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));



        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Yes View is displaying at cell's indexpath.but when i scroll cell.it remain at same indexpath.not changing

Comment: @DivineChild You need to manage the frame of the UIView's with tableview delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`.